# Where in GDB source is the transition from GDB to BFD which will interact with the memory to "apply" a breakpoint?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, bfd

I am currently investigating the GDB sources. I tried to find where the transition from GDB to BFD is where the interaction with the memory to "apply" a breakpoint is. So where the place in code is where the memory is manipulated in order to set a breakpoint.

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BFD is not involved in inserting breakpoints.

GDB has a number of mechanisms by which breakpoints can be inserted.  But if we look at just memory breakpoints then you should start looking in [gdb/mem-break.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/mem-break.c;h=111194cfb0ace8849b9255583355318582694c02;hb=HEAD).

When inserting a memory breakpoint you'll end up in `memory_insert_breakpoint`, which, for most architectures will then call to `default_memory_insert_breakpoint`.

This function then makes use of `target_read_memory` and `target_write_raw_memory` to read and write memory.

These target functions are going to do different things depending on what your target is, a native Linux target is going to use ptrace commands to poke memory, a remote target is going to send packets to the gdbserver.

You also have to consider that remote targets can support hardware breakpoints, or can also insert/remote packets using [the z/Z remote protocol packets](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html#insert-breakpoint-or-watchpoint-packet), these can all be found in [gdb/remote.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/remote.c;h=290edd07cd17912f7e146015678b2d49f5150c34;hb=HEAD), but as you specifically asked about memory breakpoints I'll not go into detail for these cases.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That was already the direction I found. I read somewhere that BFD is used by GDB and assumed that this also is used here. Where is BFD then used by GDB?

Comment: BFD provides the ability to open an executable file and extract section contents from it.  So GDB doesn't actually care if an executable is ELF or some other format, so long as BFD can understand it, GDB can handle it.  I think that's pretty much it for BFD (as far as GDB is concerned).